# How do I add a SSH key to Google Cloud Compute Engine VM Linux instance?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a Linux VM instance running in Google Cloud Platform.
I tried to copy my public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and I can successfully SSH to my VM.

But sometimes `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is flushed and I have to copy the public key again.
It is really a pain to add public key every time.
How do I add a public key permanently?

Comment: Are other files in your home dir disappearing as well (is the homedir wiped)?

Comment: No, they are just the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [Metadata-managed SSH connections](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/ssh#metadata-managed_ssh_connections) by [adding SSH keys to VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#metadata):

To add a public SSH key to project metadata using the Cloud Console, do the following:

```
1. In the Cloud Console, go to the Metadata page.

2. Go to Metadata > Under SSH Keys, click Edit.

3. Click Add item. A text box opens.

4. Add your public key in the text box. The key must be in one of the following formats:

Format for a key without an expiration time:

KEY_VALUE USERNAME
Format for a key with an expiration time:

KEY_VALUE google-ssh {"userName":"USERNAME","expireOn":"EXPIRE_TIME"}
Replace the following:

KEY_VALUE: the public SSH key value
USERNAME: the username for the SSH key, specified when the key was created
EXPIRE_TIME: the time the key expires, in ISO 8601 format. For example: 2021-12-04T20:12:00+0000
5. Click Save.
```

Be aware of the format  `Required format: <protocol> <key-blob> <username@example.com> or <protocol> <key-blob> google-ssh {"userName":"<username@example.com>","expireOn":"<date>"}`

Answer (score 0):

This ~/.ssh/authorized_keys takes the ssh keys from the metadata. It best you keep your ssh public keys in the metadata as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys) and there’s also a stack discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53379244/google-cloud-accessing-linux-vm-via-private-key/53419811#53419811)

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for which the file would "disappear" would be that every time the instance is reloaded it is reloaded from the same VM image, which doesn't contain the file. Check if the occurences are correlated with the instance reloading and if other files in your home dir disappear as well, if they do that's likely the culprit. If so I can see a couple of possible approaches:

- include the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (and, of course, your user and home directory configurations) into a [custom VM image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images) that you could then use to boot your instances from
- configure your home directory on a [persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) which would survive across instance reloads