# connect ssh to google virtual instanse always got Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I run `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
and copy `ssh-rsa AAAA...hwFbh me@me.local` into SSH Keys VM instance on google cloud and then save
and then I tried to log in on my terminal:

```
ssh my-project@ip-address
```

and then got 
`Permission denied (publickey)`

I think I do correct way to put the ssh key into my VM instance, I never success using my ssh to google cloud, but on AWS and digital ocean always no issue for this,

if i using `glcoud`

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone "us-central1-f" "my-project" --project "my-project-277520"
```

it was successfully login into my VM instance

why I want to login with command `ssh my-project@ip-address`
because if I can't access with this command I got an error on my git server, and it throw the same thing `Permission denied (publickey)` and

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can't do this `git push production master` for git hooks on that VM instance 
I am using git hooks on that server

how to resolve this thing guys? I am really stuck now for this for days :(, of course I been look on StackOverflow and googling for fix this, but I finally need to get help here for you

Comment: What is the output  of `ssh -Tv my-project@ip-address`? Please [edit] and add the long text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> copy `ssh-rsa AAAA...hwFbh me@me.loca`l into SSH Keys VM instance on google cloud and then save

It depends on how exactly you did that copy (since [you cannot directly add it to the remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53461645/6309))

For instance: "[Adding or removing project-wide public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#edit-ssh-metadata)"

[image: https://cloud.google.com/compute/images/console-remove-project-ssh-key.png]

Make sure it was copied as *one* continuous line.

Then check your local permissions (600 for the key)